# Context Free Language Question (Pumping Lemma)

Tags: theory, automata, proof, language-theory

I know this isn't directly related to programming, but I was wondering if anyone know how to apply the pumping lemma to the following proof:

> Show that *L={(a^n)(b^n)(c^m) : n!=m}* is not a context free language

I'm pretty confident with applying pumping lemmas, but this one is really irking me.  What do you think?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/ check it out

Comment: I'd say that this is one of those areas where Math and CS theory overlap.

Comment: @Jonathan: This question would typically be covered in a CS class, not a math class.  It's kind of a fuzzy area, though.  I would definitely classify it as "of interest to programmers".

Comment: @Jonathan: This is definitely not a mathoverflow.net question.  This result is widely taught in undergraduate CS; mathoverflow is for research-level mathematics.

Comment: @Charles and @Dietrich: There's a computer science tag at mathoverflow.net http://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/computer-science. Thought that would be a good place to ask this question. My apologies!!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: I was totally leading you down the wrong track.  That's what happens when I try to help out when I haven't completely solved the problem myself.

### Ogden's Lemma

Suppose L is context free.  By Ogden's lemma, there exists an integer p that has the following properties:

Given a string w in L at least p symbols long, where at least p of those symbols are "marked", w can be represented as uvxyz, which satisfy:

1. x has at least one marked symbol,
2. either u and v both have marked symbols or y and z both have marked symbols,
3. vxy has at most p marked symbols, and
4. u v<sup>i</sup> x y<sup>i</sup> z is in L for i >= 0

That's Ogden's lemma.  Now, let q be an integer divisible by every positive integer no greater than p.  Let w = a<sup>p+q</sup> b<sup>p+q</sup> c<sup>p</sup>.  Mark every c.  By #2, u or v must contain at least one c.  If either u or v contains any other symbol, then #4 fails, so u and v must contain only c.  But then #4 fails when i = q/|uv|.  We know q is divisible by |uv| because p > |uv| > 0, and q is divisible by all positive integers less than p.

Note that Ogden's lemma turns into the pumping lemma when you mark all symbols.

### Pumping Lemma

Suppose L is context free.  By the pumping lemma, there is a length p (not necessarily the same p as above) such that any string w in L can be represented as uvxyz, where

1. |vxy| <= p,
2. |vy| >= 1, and
3. u v<sup>i</sup> x y<sup>i</sup> z is in L for i >= 0.

Given a string w in L, either m > n or m < n.  Suppose p = 2.

Suppose that m > n. (Note that Λ denotes the empty string.)

- Let u = a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>n</sup> c<sup>m-1</sup>
- Let v = c
- Let x = Λ
- Let y = Λ
- Let z = Λ

Suppose that n > m.

- Let u = a<sup>n-1</sup>
- Let v = a
- Let x = Λ
- Let y = b
- Let z = b<sup>n-1</sup> c<sup>m</sup>

This demonstrates that no string from L provides a counterexample using the pumping lemma to the supposition that L is a context free language (even though it is context sensitive).

Comment: I don't follow...though this would prevent the pumped selection from including all 3 characters, it wouldn't stop the selected pump section from being all C's, which necessarily be pumped to equal n

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the pumping lemma when I looked it up.  I believe this requires Ogden's lemma, which is stronger.  Fixed.

Comment: 'requires Ogden's lemma' in that it's not provable w/ the pumping lemma?

Comment: I put up my proof with Ogden's lemma.  Sorry for the unhelpful hints earlier.

Comment: So ogden's lemma is the only choice?  Thanks a bunch for the insight!