# Is the language A = {0^n 1^n 0^n} context free?

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

I was just putting some thought into different languages (as I'm reviewing for final exams coming up) and I can not think of a valid pushdown automata to handle the language A = {0^n 1^n 0^n | n >= 0}.  This is not a context-free language, am I correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617675/theory-of-computation-using-the-pumping-lemma-for-context-free-languages

Comment: @Andrew These are separate languages :)

Comment: @Andrew: plus, "regular" and "context-free" are entirely different *classes* of languages

Comment: Also, these questions are both from the same asker, so I *hope* he'd know if they were the same question or not (though I admit it's not a given)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are. It looks quite similar to the language *L = { a^i b^i c^i  | i > 0 }* which the Wikipedia article on [the pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) uses as an example of how to prove that a language is not context-free.

Comment: To the original poster, I would suggest attempting to follow through the same steps of the proof referred to above with the language you're interested in.

Comment: that language fails the pumping lemma for CFLS

Answer (score 1):

Think of just the {0^n 1^n} part for a second.  Replace `0` with `(` and `1` with `)` and you've got the language of simple nested parentheses, which is a dead give-away that a language is not regular.

Adding the final 0^n makes it context-sensitive (i.e. not context-free).  Keep in mind that a CFG can be decided by a finite-state computer with a single stack as its only data structure.  Seeing a 0 will cause a character to be pushed onto the stack, and seeing a 1 will pop from the stack.  This guarantees that there are as many 0's as 1's, but there's no way to then match *more* 0's.