# Why the following language cannot be defined using a Pushdown Automata (PDA)?

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata, computation-theory, pushdown-automaton

{0 <sup>i</sup>1 <sup>j</sup>2 <sup>k</sup> | 0 <= i <= j <= k }

Is it possible to design a PDA for this language?

I think the answer is no, and it can only be defined using at least a context free grammar.

However, I don't know why. I need some discussion and explanation regarding this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597124/context-free-language-question-pumping-lemma

Comment: @ComputerDruid thanks for the note. I didn't know about the Ogden's lemma. However, I do want to know why there can't be a PDA for this language. I think it would be somehow possible to design a PDA, it would be hard I think but still possible.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Actually there are neither a CFG nor an NPDA for this language.
The proof can be established using a pumping lemma for context free languages.